# I'm a student stuck on a basic Rock, Paper Scissors practice problem

Tags: c

I'm working on a practice problem that wants me to write a basic game of rock, paper scissors. Well, I think I've completed the challenge because I'm not getting getting any console errors or warnings. However, when I run my code I'm being prompted to enter a command but when I do so the program ends.

Does anyone see where I went wrong?

For a beginner what steps should I take if I see no errors or warnings in the console? How do you even know where to begin to debug?

Thanks.

my last error was in the userChoice() function. I think my problem has something to do with me using strcmp().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>


/* create a game of rock paper scissors*/

    char userInputString[9];
    int userInput;
    int computerInput;

/* Creates a random number between 1-3  the computer can
use as it's random choice for rock, paper or scissors.*/

 void computerChoice(){

    srand(time(NULL));
    int dice = rand()%3+1;

    if( dice = 1){

       int computerInput = 1;

    }else if( dice = 2){

        int computerInput = 2;

    }else if( dice = 3) {

        char computerInput = 3;

    }else{
        printf("Error! Something went wrong.");

    }

 }

/* Takes the rock, paper or scissors string typed by the user and converts it in to a number between 1-3
    that can be used to compare with the computers choice.*/


 void userChoice(){

     if(strcmp(userInputString,"rock")){

            userInput = 1;

     }else if(strcmp(userInputString,"paper")){

            userInput = 2;

     }else if(strcmp(userInputString,"scissors")){

            userInput = 3;
     }else{

        printf("Error! Something went wrong.\n");

     }

 }


/* compares the user and the computers choice then prints a winner to the console */

void compare(){

    switch(computerInput){

        case 1 : if(userInput = 1){
            printf("Computer picked Rock! It's a draw!\n");

        }else if(userInput = 2){
            printf("Computer picked Rock! You win!\n");

        }else if(userInput = 3){
            printf("Computer picked Rock! You lose!\n");

        }else{
            printf("Oops something went wrong.\n");

        }

        case 2 : if(userInput = 1){
            printf("Computer picked Paper! You lose!\n");

        }else if(userInput = 2){
            printf("Computer picked Paper! It's a draw!\n");

        }else if(userInput = 3){
            printf("Computer picked Paper! You win!\n");

        }else{
            printf("Oops something went wrong.\n");

        }case 3 : if(userInput = 1){
            printf("Computer picked scissors! You win!\n");

        }else if(userInput = 2){
            printf("Computer picked scissors! You lose!\n");

        }else if(userInput = 3){
            printf("Computer picked scissors! it's a draw!\n");

        }else{
            printf("Oops something went wrong.\n");

        }
    }
}

int main() {

        printf("Type rock, paper or scissors: \n");
        scanf("%s", &userInputString);

        computerChoice();
        userChoice();
        compare();

    return 0;
}
```

I expect a basic functional game of rock, paper, scissors.

Comment: "*How do you even know where to begin to debug*" - divide and conquer. See [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `if(dice = 2)` doesn't just compare `dice` against 2. It assigns it and checks if it's nonzero. You almost certainly meant `if(dice == 2)`.

Comment: @Fureeish. Neat article. Definitely a should-read for beginners.

Comment: Your `strcmp` calls in `userChoice` should be (e.g.) `if (strcmp(userInputString,"rock") == 0)` and _not_ `if (strcmp(userInputString,"rock")`

Comment: The `case` statements in `compare` should have `break` between them

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note other compilers use different options to produce the same thing.  the posted code results in some 25 warnings from the compiler.  BTW: suggest learning the syntax for the `switch()` statement and related `case` and `default` statements and how to write a comparison within an `if()` statement

Comment: OT:  regarding: `scanf("%s", &userInputString);`  when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the input format specifiers: '%s' and/or '%[...]' always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This avoids the possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior.

Comment: OT: in general, global variables should be avoided.  Better to declare the variables in `main()` and pass pointers to those variables when calling any sub functions.

Comment: Thank you all for the information, this was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
if( dice = 1){

   int computerInput = 1;

}
```

Here (and elsewhere) you are creating a new local variable whose lifetime ends when the block ends.

Remove the `int` declarator so the statement modifies the existing file-scope variable.

Also, use `==` for comparison. `=` assigns a new value to the variable, which is not what you want here.

```
if(strcmp(userInputString,"rock")){

        userInput = 1;

 }
```

`strcmp()` returns 0 if the two strings match. So add `== 0` to the condition.